nvidia drivers ubuntu 24.04, legacy gpu, external display gray screen or not working
I ran across this issue today and found a solution, I am unable to post comments due to lack of reputation points but figured others are having this same issue so here is the answer
Leading off of this thread
If anyone is experiencing this same issue, and sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550 did not work, and you are running a legacy gpu - you might want to try an older version of the nvidia driver that works for your graphics card.
My graphics card
graphics card: GK107GLM [Quadro K1000M]
My Solution:

v470 works
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470

